# Add a second label to an inherited node in spring-data-neo4j-4

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Let's have this class structure:

```
@NodeEntity
abstract class BasicNodeEntity {
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;
    //...
}

abstract class IdentifiableEntity extends BasicNodeEntity {
    private String id;
    //...
}

abstract class Ad extends IdentifiableEntity {
    //... Ad attibutes
}

class OfferAd extends Ad {
    // ... OfferAd attibutes
}
```

Saving an `OfferAd` node through a `Neo4jRepository`, I expect the node would have two labels: `OfferAd` and `Ad` (inherited). However, the label `Ad` is not added to the node.

I know I can do it saving the node through a cypher query, but I'm wondering if it's posible through a `Neo4jRepository` instead.

I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769749/how-do-i-add-a-second-label-to-a-node-in-spring-data-neo4j-3-0-0-release) (related to SDN3) and I think it's very close to my use case, but it seems to be not working...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules for labels are as follows:

- any plain concrete class in the hierarchy generates a label by default
- plain abstract class does not generate a label by default
- plain interface does not generate a label by default
- any class annotated with @NodeEntity or @NodeEntity(label="something") generates a label
- empty or null labels must not be allowed
- classes / hierarchies that are not to be persisted must be annotated with @Transient

Therefore if you remove abstract from your base class, or add a `@NodeEntity` annotation, you should see the results you expect.

Additionally (new in OGM 2.0.4 and fixes in 2.0.5), you can add and remove additional labels by creating a field of type `Collection<String>` and annotating it with `@Labels`, for example:

```
@Labels
private List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
```

To use version 2.0.4 (gradle):

```
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:{version}"
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:{version}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed rules for labels explanation.

Comment: You're welcome @troig :) Let us know if you have any issues getting 2.0.4/5 integrated.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as adding the `@NodeEntity` annotation to the `Ad` class as well. 
It seems to be that `spring-data-neo4j-4` only creates one label per node by default, even if the node inherites another one.

If we want to allow SDN to add the parent label classes as well, we need to add `@NodeEntity` to them.

So, for this use case, if we add it to `Ad` class,

```
@NodeEntity
abstract class Ad extends IdentifiableEntity {
   //... Ad attibutes
}
```

when we save an `OfferAd` through a `Neo4jRepository`, the node created will have both labels: `Ad` and `OfferAd`.

[image]